# Being able to use flash messages in passport even when FailureFlash = false

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local, connect-flash

I have been working with passport local-strategy for a little while now and noticed that the failureFlash boolean doesnt seem too impact whether or not a flash message is shown or not. This is the code:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
                    successRedirect: '/',
                    failureRedirect: '/',
                    failureFlash: false
                    })
```

somewhere in the local-strategy:

```
return done(null, false,  req.flash('error','Invalid username or password.'));
```

When the page renders:

```
res.render(__dirname + '/../public/views/main',{ error: req.flash('error')});
```

In this scenario a flash message is sent to the client which doesn't make sense to me, shouldn't this only be possible if failureflash is true? Any help much appreciated.